# Bootstrap form validation loading modal not working in safari

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, validation, safari, modal-dialog

I'm using a bootstrap form validator which activates a modal when loading the next page. It works well on Chrome and Firefox, but the modal does not appear on Safari, even though the form is validated..
I'm not sure if it's a css issue or a javascript issue. Any help, or pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. :)

(I'm new to StackOverflow sorry if I have not formatted the code correctly)
Thanks!

**the html**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="process" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-md" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body text-center">
          <img src="img/process.gif" class="center-block">
          <div class="processmessage">
              Please be patient ...<br>
              Processing may take a few moments.
              </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**the javascript**

```
    $('#paymentform').validator().on('submit', function (e) {
      if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
      } else {
        $('#process').modal({
            backdrop: 'static',  
            keyboard: false  
        })  

      }
    })

}
```

**What I'm referencing**

http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/?underwear=on

Comment: did you try with `$('#process').modal('show');`

Comment: Yes I did, Shehary. The same thing continues to happen..
What's odd is moving forward to the next page does not show the modal on safari, but if I hit the back button on the browser to go back one page (to the original page where the modal should show) it shows, but instead of showing and then disappears, it stays forever and I have to refresh the page to get rid of it! So it doesn't show going forward, but shows going backward. :/